# How do I add a line of text to the middle of a file using awk?

Tags: awk

This is an great answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6739327/15603477
But Still a little bit confused me.

without `a` variable, `awk '/^nameserver/  { printf("nameserver 127.0.0.1\n")} {print}' file2` will get:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain dhcp.example.com
search dhcp.example.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.2
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.3
```

After try serval combination, I found out that I had to use
`awk '/^nameserver/ && !a { printf("nameserver 127.0.0.1\n"); a=1 } {print}' file2`

But I am still confused with `!a` and `a=1` function to stop the `printf("nameserver 127.0.0.1\n")` duplication.

Comment: `printf("nameserver 127.0.0.1\n")` =  `print "nameserver 127.0.0.1"`. When asking a question it's fine to refer to a previous question/answer but make sure your current question has the sample input, expected output, and code that you're asking about such that it makes sense stand-alone and the people reading it don't **need** to look up the previous question for context and necessary info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the use of these kind of variables known as "flag variable", that let the program knows a certain condition has met then decide based on its value for further processing; here that's a simple control flag that whenever it doesn't set and has 0 or empty value (in [awk default variables' value](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html) is 0 when doing integer comparison or its empty string when doing string comparison) then the string will be printed and the flag `a=1` will be set, and so it will stop adding duplicates since that's now non-zero value.

In many programming languages, `!` (not) negates the evaluation result of an statement which when it's used like `! a`, it negates the evaluation result of the `a` variable, if `a=0`, then `! a` will retun 1, or will retun 0 if it was `a=1`.

Answer (score 7):

Name the variable `already_inserted` instead of `a` and it will become clear. Then it reads like:

```
if my_pattern matches and not already_inserted { insert "some text"; already_inserted=true; }
```

`awk` will run this command for each line.